# Using maven-release-plugin with git over HTTPS

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to use the maven release plugin with git over https(for some obscure reason, I can't use git over ssh), however, I am getting receiving the following error message:

```
14:36:52 [ERROR] The git-push command failed.
14:36:52 [ERROR] Command output:
14:36:52 [ERROR] fatal: could not read Username for 'https://my.company.git.host.com': No such device or address
14:36:52 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Looking over the web, I have figured to set the following properties on my **pom.xml** file:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://my.company.git.host.com/Project/project.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://my.company.git.host.com/Project/project.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

And the following has been added to my **settings.xml**(located under `~/.m2` folder. I have checked that by running maven with `-X` flag)

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>my.company.git.host.com</id>
            <username>svc.jenkins.project</username>
            <password>guesswhat</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

**Important note**:
If I add the user/password directly in `connection` and `developerConnection` attributes, like bellow, it works properly.

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://user:password@my.company.git.host.com/Project/project.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://user:password@my.company.git.host.com/Project/project.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

Is that correct? My guess is that the release plugin is not compatible with git over https however, I'd to get some confirmation about that.

Comment: A git repository usually ends with `.git` which is not the case for your developerConnections.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for the alert. I have fixed the typo on pom.xml.

Comment: A question what i missed. Which version of the maven-release-plugin do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise the latest stable release - 2.5.3, besides maven 3.0.5. I have noted also that if I add the user:password@hostname in the connection/developerConnection attributes, it works properly. I have added that on the question as well.

Comment: How have you called the release plugin via `mvn release:prepare` and afterwards `mvn release:perform`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, my conclusion is that the release plugin is not able to recover the password from external file when used with an https connection. So the best way I've found is to provide the password along the url, in the following format:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://user:password@my.company.git.host.com/Project/project.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://user:password@my.company.git.host.com/Project/project.git</developerConnection>

</scm>
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to point out, you can avoid specifying the password in the `<connection></connection>` by defining the password in `settings.xml` and configuring the maven release plugin with the username/password properties

Comment: it is recommended to keep the username and password in settings.xml which is not on SCM.
you should not commit any credentials/secret on version control and keep them on local.
also you can check the official documentation https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/faq.html#credentials

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is very old, but I discover it now. When you call maven prepare, you can set user and password in command line parameter :

```
mvn release:prepare -DreleaseVersion=1.2 -DdevelopmentVersion=2.0-SNAPSHOT -Dtag=my-tag1.2 -Dusername=YYYYY -Dpassword=XXXXXX
```

Works with mavern-release-plugin 2.5.3

Regards,